# Showing tab bar after login form iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm implementing an application, where I show a view with a navigation item button that shows a modal view. This modal view shows a login form. In case the login is correct, I would like to go to another view thats shows a tab bar with 2 or 3 controllers.
So far, in my AppDelegate I've got:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES; }
```

and then, in my RooViewController I've got:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
HomeViewController *homeController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
self.controladorVistaHome = homeController;
[self.view addSubview:homeController.view];
[homeController release];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" style:  UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showModalLoginForm)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Register" style:  UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showModalRegisterForm)];
[super viewDidLoad]; }
```

When I click to the login button, it shows me a modal view with the form. Once the user logs in, I would like to show a nab bar view with some controllers.
If I modify my AppDelegate, then what I've got so far wouldn't work. Is there a way to make this work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a `UITabBarController` is the absolute root of your App & then you add `UINavigationControllers` to each Tab View as needed.

I'd recommend changing your `self.window.rootViewController` to be a `UITabBarController` (this will be the main hub of your app once users are logged in).
Then on first launch, if a user isn't logged in you throw up a modal View that allows them to log in OR register.

If log in is a success, dismiss the modal view. Then you'll be back at your Tab Bar ready to for the App's main use.

If a user doesn't have a log in, show ANOTHER modal view to register which will dismiss back to the original log in modal view once done (or perhaps even just log the user in automatically & thus be dismissed).

Comment: In what part should I throw up the modal view on first launch? In my AppDelegate? I feel confusing by modifying the AppDelegate...

Comment: And all of this verifications (user logged in, user logged out...) should I make them on the AppDelegate?

Comment: Dont' be scared of modifying the AppDelegate, but I'd look at creating a UITabBarController subclass that handles the show/dismiss of the Modal View...